# How to arrange table and chart both are in same line using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to arrange the chart table in same line in my html code chart is above and table is below which not visible clearly how to re arrange it with below code i am not able to see the full table thanks in advance

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2">

        <title> BATTERY VOLTAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="mt-2 mb-3 text-center text-primary">BATTERY VOLTAGE</h1>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-9">Battery Voltage</div>
                        <div class="col col-sm-3">
                            <input type="text" id="daterange_textbox" class="form-control" readonly />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive" >
                        <div class="chart-container pie-chart" "width:60%" >
                        <div border="1" 
                                      align="left" >
                            <canvas id="bar_chart" height="90"> </canvas>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                         <table class="column">

                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="order_table" style="width:40%" align="right">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="5%">Order Number</th>
                                    <th width="6%">Order Value</th>
                                    <th width="6%">Order Date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: how to arrange the graph and table same row]

Comment: Please resolve the issues with your code so that it reproduces your problem, but doesn't generate additional errors in the console, as your current code does: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Comment: The problem was with the <script> tag at the end. I removed it.

Comment: There are other problems with the snippet that don't cause any errors but cause it to fail to render properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to arrange the chart and table in the same line use CSS to control the width, positioning of each element, set the width of the chart to 60% and the width of the table to 40%, and floated both elements to the left and right

```
    <title> BATTERY VOLTAGE</title>
    
    <style>
        .chart-container {
            width: 60%;
            float: left;
        }
        .table-container {
            width: 40%;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-2 mb-3 text-center text-primary">BATTERY VOLTAGE</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-sm-9">Battery Voltage</div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" id="daterange_textbox" class="form-control" readonly />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="chart-container pie-chart">
                    <div border="1" 
                                  align="left" >
                        <canvas id="bar_chart" height="90"> </canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-container">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="order_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="5%">Order Number</th>
                                <th width="6%">Order Value</th>
                                <th width="6%">Order Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `float` is rarely a good solution and mostly is good only when you want text to wrap around an element.